# How to send data from an android app to html and receive info back?

Tags: android, webview, http-post, http-get

I need to send three pieces of information:
A domain, an email, and a mobile identifier.

From the website, I expect to get back a JSON response looking like this:

```
{
domain: example.com,
token: abcdefg123,
reportEmail: null,
mobileResultsPageUrl: http://completedtest.testingSite.com/mobile/abcdefg123/4a0ced51c00cfd5d6ce8b50d00be49f6
}
```

I care most about the Url that will be shown as a Webview in a new activity.

This is what I'm trying so far:

```
public void postData(){
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://exampleTestingSite.com/");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("domain", "OswaldMagic.com"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sendReportTo", "me@gmail.com"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", "1"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Take care and talk soon, 
-Stefan

Comment: You cannot post data to html. Well you tried something. How far did you get? Please give an extended report. Don't let us guess.

Comment: I haven't gotten far at all. Are you saying that we can only take data from a website? Is there a way for us to use a website as a tool to process data?

Comment: Everything you want is ok and doable. There are many standard ways. You want nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now working!

We have to let the website know that we expect to be returned a JSON because the default is set to HTML. We do this by modifying the header to accept JSON, see the code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

After I got the expected results, I needed to use only one part of the JSON. First I took the result from the site and converted it to a String:

```
resultHTML = Html.fromHtml(responseBody);

JSONObject obj = null;
try {
    obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(resultHTML));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String resultsPageHTML = null;
try {
    resultsPageHTML = obj.getString("mobileResultsPageUrl");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then I called sharedPreferences:

```
// create a file to save SharedPreferences in
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";
// call sharedPreferences
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
// call SharedPreferences editor
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("resultsPageHTML", resultsPageHTML);
editor.commit();
```

So that I could receive it in another activity.

I hope this helps someone who is going through similar struggles.